# What set do these two belong to? curved white spaceship with red stripe stickers

Tags: set-identification

Am having trouble finding the set.
[image: curved white spaceship with red stripe stickers]

Answer (score 4):

[75249-1 Resistance Y-Wing Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75249-1) based on Light Bluish Gray Tile, Modified Facet 2 x 2 and Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 1 x 4 Offset (which is a weird name) - there are 4 sets, and only 1 has those stickers.

[image: 75249]